# How can I check the model of my Apple computer?

Tags: hardware

Is there a way that I check the model number of my Apple computer? (For example, `iMac9,1`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [System Profiler](http://guides.macrumors.com/System_Profiler)

In the left corner of the top menu, pick the apple menu and select `About This Mac`.

In the `About This Mac` panel, click the `More Info...` button. This starts the System Profiler.

On the first page (Hardware Overview) there is a `Model Identifier`, which is the name you are interested in.